# Convert INF(Installation Instructions)to EXE Installer

Tags: installation, click, exe, inf

I have an INF file in which I have to right click to install the files - So I wanted to convert it into a EXE Installer which has a Progress Bar !!! So I just need all the files in ONE EXE file so when I double click it the installation starts ...

Regards,
Netguy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

First, create a .bat file with the following command:

```
rundll32 syssetup,SetupInfObjectInstallAction DefaultInstall 128 .\inffile.inf
```

for each .inf file. This command will install your file.

Then, start iexpress, this program is provided with windows. Follow the wizard. When asked to add files, add all your .inf files and the .bat file. When asked for the install script, select the .bat file.

That should do it.

Regards, 
Patrik

Comment: Yeah , but the problem is on some comps while installing OS XP I get an error that the file is missing i.e. the temporary files get deleted very fast any Idea for that ?

Comment: Is the error something like this? `Error creating process <file> Reason: The system cannot find the file specified.` Or what is the error exactly?